# Nested NSPredicate predicateWithBlock is not working

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have an array of objects which in-turn has another array of objects (second level), my requirement is to do a filter based on the values in second level.  So am using nested predicateWithBlock, but I don't get the desired output.

```
NSMutableArray *topLevelArray;
[topLevelArray filterUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:^BOOL(id evaluatedObject, NSDictionary *bindings) {
    NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:^BOOL(id evaluatedObject, NSDictionary *bindings) {
        CustomType2 *obj2 = (CustomType2 *)evaluatedObject;
        if ([obj2.name rangeOfString:searchText options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch].location != NSNotFound)
        {
            return YES;
        }
        else
        {
            return NO;
        }
    }];
    CustomType1 *obj1 = (CustomType1 *)evaluatedObject;
    [obj1.customType2 filteredSetUsingPredicate:pred];
    return YES;
}]];
```

**Input:**

```
topLevelArray = {
  [CustomType1.name = "Alpha",
    CustomType1.customType2 = {
      [CustomType2.name = "Apple"], 
      [CustomType2.name = "Banana"], 
      [CustomType2.name = "Cocoplum"]}
  ],
  [CustomType1.name = "Beta",
    CustomType1.customType2 = {
      [CustomType2.name = "Asparagus"], 
      [CustomType2.name = "Broccoli"]}
  ],
  [CustomType1.name = "Gama",
    CustomType1.customType2 = {
      [CustomType2.name = "Aligator"]}
  ]};
```

**Output:**

```
    searchText = @"Bro";
    topLevelArray = {
      [CustomType1.name = "Alpha",
        CustomType1.customType2 = {
          [CustomType2.name = "Apple"], 
          [CustomType2.name = "Banana"], 
          [CustomType2.name = "Cocoplum"]}
      ],
      [CustomType1.name = "Beta",
        CustomType1.customType2 = {
          [CustomType2.name = "Asparagus"], 
          [CustomType2.name = "Broccoli"]}
      ],
      [CustomType1.name = "Gama",
        CustomType1.customType2 = {
          [CustomType2.name = "Aligator"]}
      ]};
```

**Expected Output:**

```
searchText = @"Bro";
topLevelArray = {
  [CustomType1.name = "Alpha",
    CustomType1.customType2 = {nil}
  ],
  [CustomType1.name = "Beta",
    CustomType1.customType2 = {
      [CustomType2.name = "Broccoli"]}
  ],
  [CustomType1.name = "Gama",
    CustomType1.customType2 = {nil}
  ]};
```

Comment: Note the difference between `[filteredSetUsingPredicate:]` and `[filterUsingPredicate:]`

Comment: `if (something) return YES; else return NO;` oh no... why can't you just `return something;`

Comment: you need to search the data in the customtype2 object, Am I right.

Comment: @borrrden I have NSSet property, so have used [filteredSetUsingPredicate].

Comment: @RameshMuthe you are right

Comment: What I am saying is that look up what `[filteredSetUsingPredicate:]` actually does...

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you will have to iterate through your array, applying a predicate to each object:

```
NSArray *topLevelArray = @[[CustomType1 typeOneWithName:@"Alpha" typeTwoObjects:@[[CustomType2 typeTwoWithName:@"Apple"],[CustomType2 typeTwoWithName:@"Banana"],[CustomType2 typeTwoWithName:@"Cocoplum"]]],
                           [CustomType1 typeOneWithName:@"Beta"  typeTwoObjects:@[[CustomType2 typeTwoWithName:@"Asparagus"],[CustomType2 typeTwoWithName:@"Broccoli"]]],
                           [CustomType1 typeOneWithName:@"Gamma" typeTwoObjects:@[[CustomType2 typeTwoWithName:@"Aligator"]]]];

NSString *searchTerm = @"Bro";
NSPredicate *titlePredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name like[cd] %@", [NSString stringWithFormat:@"*%@*", searchTerm]];
NSMutableArray *results = [NSMutableArray array];
[topLevelArray enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(CustomType1 *obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    [results addObject:[CustomType1 typeOneWithName:obj.name typeTwoObjects:[obj.typeTwoObjects filteredArrayUsingPredicate:titlePredicate]]];
}];

NSLog(@"topLevelArray = %@", topLevelArray);
NSLog(@"Search for '%@' = %@", searchTerm, results);
```

Which yields:

```
2014-10-08 20:35:05.173 MyApp[3577:1940746] topLevelArray = (
    "<CustomType1 0x15e545d0; name='Alpha'; typeTwoObjects=[<CustomType2 0x15e774b0; name='Apple'>, <CustomType2 0x15e70840; name='Banana'>, <CustomType2 0x15e66740; name='Cocoplum'>]>",
    "<CustomType1 0x15e52c70; name='Beta'; typeTwoObjects=[<CustomType2 0x15e74ed0; name='Asparagus'>, <CustomType2 0x15e74600; name='Broccoli'>]>",
    "<CustomType1 0x15e50290; name='Gamma'; typeTwoObjects=[<CustomType2 0x15e52c80; name='Aligator'>]>"
)
2014-10-08 20:35:05.196 MyApp[3577:1940746] Search for 'Bro' = (
    "<CustomType1 0x15e7a090; name='Alpha'; typeTwoObjects=[]>",
    "<CustomType1 0x15e7a2e0; name='Beta'; typeTwoObjects=[<CustomType2 0x15e74600; name='Broccoli'>]>",
    "<CustomType1 0x15e7a2f0; name='Gamma'; typeTwoObjects=[]>"
)
```

Above I'm building a new array of objects. You could just as easily mutate the original array. For example, replace the enumeration loop above with:

```
[topLevelArray enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(CustomType1 *obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    obj.typeTwoObjects = [obj.typeTwoObjects filteredArrayUsingPredicate:titlePredicate];
}];
```

This will obviously discard any data not matching the predicate, but perhaps that's what you wanted to do.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  But my custom object has multiple properties, which wouldn't be effective to initialize every value with the new object for 'results' array.  Is there an alternate solution to this?

Comment: @immasara You obviously could, rather than creating a new array of `CustomType1` objects, you could mutate the existing array of objects. See final code snippet in my revised answer.

Comment: Custom objects array is getting wiped off as the mutableCopy method doesn't give a duplicate object, but does a reference copy.

Comment: Yeah, sure: You'd have to do a deep copy if you want new objects in your new array. But if you're creating new objects, then the original answer, which creates the new array is going be more efficient than creating a mutable deep copy and then mutating it.